# New users vs Update user for iOS app

Tags: ios, flurry

We had an app live on the Apple app store for several months and that app  did not include Flurry analytics.

We have recently updated the app with a new version and also included Flurry analytics into the App.

The Flurry dashboard is reporting the "New users" correctly when compared to new users iTunes sales and trends report however, iTunes is also reporting several hundered "updates" of the app that have been downloaded - however these are not included in the "New user" count on Flurry.

This means that Flurry is only reporting actual new app downloads and not considering app updates as new users at all?

We are using the Appcelerator module of Flurry.

Please could you help me in understanding if we need to do anything special/extra while integrating flurry SDK into the app to ensure users who take updates of the app are also included in the new users count in Flurry.

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to find people to email you soltions to your problem. The goal is for your question and its answer to be posted here for others to find and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

A interesting fact.

Try create event with param with universal name (for see count of events in circle in Event Parameters), and send at once from each device.

Then you can take a count of all active users. But if user is reinstall the app, then him can send at secondly, what is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Flurry can’t report updating users as “updating users” because it only just found out about them. As far as Flurry is concerned, *all* of your users are new, because it hasn’t seen any of them before. When you release a second version with Flurry you will get the correct metrics. (Except, of course, for the hopefully-small minority who are updating directly from your 1.0 release.)

**Edit:** I think I’ve completely misunderstood your question. I think your mismatch may be caused by the fact that Flurry can only report on users who have launched [the new version of] your app at least once, while iTunes Connect will report *all* of the new and updating users.

Comment: well, The problem we are facing is that since we have updated the app from version 1.0 (no flurry) to 1.1 (with flurry), there have been approx 50 new downloads every day and approx 600 updates every day. this is reflected in iTunes however Flurry is only showing 50 each day as the increase in the count of new users and totally missing out on the users who have taken the update - which actually should be treated as new users because that is the first time their device would have been detected when they would have opened the app. have you heard of a similar issue before and a solution? thanks